# unable to install psycopg2 on Mac, OSError: Errno13 permission denied

Tags: python, postgresql, terminal, pip

I installed postgreSQL from the website. I tried running the following code on terminal

```
pip install psycopg2
```

But this error came:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: recommend using a virtualenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo pip install psycopg2
```

try this as on unix environment you need superuser permission to write to os containing partition

Comment: It worked. Can you edit pyscopg2 to psycopg2? I made a typo. But the problem now is, python says "no such directory" when I run "import psycopg2"

Comment: you need to run it with superuser priviledge. are you importing it to idle??

Comment: No. I am using terminal with sublime text.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working fine. I tried using some queries on it as well.